# Log4j on Websphere LEVEL NULL

Tags: java, logging, log4j, websphere

So, I have a legacy application using mainly Apache Commons Logging but a few things are made using Log4J. In my case I have to use Log4J to write some logs when a user delete something to a specific file, the name of the file is only known at runtime, so what I did is to have a logger in log4j.xml :

```
<logger name="DELETE_LOGGER" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
</logger>
```

And in a servlet that is loaded at the start of the application, I have :

```
RollingFileAppender appender = new RollingFileAppender(
        new PatternLayout(PATTERN),
        deleteFileName);
appender.setMaxBackupIndex(1);
appender.setMaxFileSize("1MB");
appender.setName("DELETE_APPENDER");
appender.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
appender.setAppend(true);
appender.activateOptions();
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("DELETE_LOGGER");
logger.removeAllAppenders();
logger.addAppender(appender);
```

And then I have a utility class with :

```
Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("DELETE_LOGGER");
LOGGER.info(message);
```

I is working without any issues on my Tomcat, on Websphere the file was created but nothing was logged. I finally figured out that the logger level on Websphere was **null** and not **INFO**. Does anyone know why ? The log4j.xml is ok, I don't understand.

Comment: There is setting in WebSphere where you edit the log detail level. Make sure you have the right setting.

Comment: I have looked into "Change Log Detail Levels" of Websphere and only found an input with "*=info: fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.sort.SortUtil=all: fr.improve.struts.*=all" and a list without my logger, this doesn't look related to Log4J.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope I agree, changing the WebSphere log details is unlikely to affect log4j.  Unfortunately, I don't know enough about log4j to suggest why the log4j.xml config is not being observed.  It might be easiest to add some diagnostic logic into the log4j code to determine why the configuration is not working.

Comment: @Aramiti These settings are for Java Util Logging which is used by WAS. They have nothing to do with log4j.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
Try omit underscore ('_') in logger name.
Try use "DELETELOGGER" insted of "DELETE_LOGGER".